# Why does Amplify for AWS Cognito send new passwords in plain text when SRP is enabled?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, srp-protocol

We are using Amplify with AWS Cognito, using SRP.
From our understanding of SRP, passwords should not be sent in plain text over the network.

When the user is required to change their password on login, we use the Auth.completeNewPassword method. Looking at the request, the password is clearly sent in plain text.
Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because even in SRP you need to send the password at least once to the server.

When you sign up or change your password you send two values to the server: `username` and `password`. The server generates a new salt for that `username` and calculates a value called `verifier` using (among others) `username`, `password` and `salt`. Then it stores the following information: `username`, `salt` and `verifier`.

From now on you no longer need password to be sent over the wire.